# How to read a file and convert in a structure dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file DD03.txt describe structure of different DataFrame like
[image: File]

I would like to convert it in to dataframe
df1 called BBKPF
df2 called BBSEG

And for BBKPF, the strucute of the Dataframe as to be

```
BBKPF = {'STYPE': str 1, 'TCODE': str 20 ...}
BBSEG = ...
```

Like I'm a newbie, I need some help to find how to convert the file with description on my target dataframe in dataframe.

Thanks in advance,

Philippe

Comment: What do you mean by `str 1` and `str 20`?

Comment: Hello, I have to populate a file with len for each field, when I'm writting some code in ABAP, we can describe the len of the field as 1 for 1 digit ...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df0 = pd.read_csv('DD03.txt')
df1 = df0.loc[df0['Nom de la table'] == 'BBKPF']
df2 = df0.loc[df0['Nom de la table'] == 'BBSEG']
```

Comment: Hi, I have written code as `df0 = pd.read_csv(fichier)
    df1 = df0.loc[df0['Table'] == 'BBKPF']
    df2 = df0.loc[df0['Table'] == 'BBSEG']` and got an error message: **KeyError: 'Table'**  I have renamed the header of the column as Table and Zone

Comment: I found my error by adding the separator. the result now is not what i would like, when I print df1, I have the list of fields. `    Table      Zone
0   BBKPF     STYPE
1   BBKPF     TCODE
2   BBKPF     BLDAT
3   BBKPF     BLART ` My goal is to have a Dataframe with the columns STYPE| TCODE | BLDAT| ... Thanks for your proposal